# sed escape /var/run/saslauthd

Tags: sed

I want to remove this line from `fstab` using `sed`:

```
/var/run/saslauthd /export/sasl none bind 0 0
```

I know a workaround, first give the number of line,
then remove it with `sed`, but I want to know
how to escape the three `/`?

I have tried a lot but none of these works:

```
sed  /^/var/run/saslauthd/d /etc/fstab
sed  /^\/var\/run\/saslauthd/d /etc/fstab
sed  /^"/var\/run\/saslauthd"/d /etc/fstab
sed  ^"/var\/run\/saslauthd"/d /etc/fstab
sed  ^"/var/run/saslauthd"/d /etc/fstab
sed  ^/var/run/saslauthd:d /etc/fstab
sed  :^/var/run/saslauthd:d /etc/fstab
sed  :^"/var/run/saslauthd":d /etc/fstab
sed  :^\/var\/run\/saslauthd":d /etc/fstab
sed  :^\/var\/run\/saslauthd:d /etc/fstab
sed  :^//var/run/saslauthd:d /etc/fstab
sed  ^//var/run/saslauthd:d /etc/fstab
```

Comment: @elbarna; Why not just use `grep -v` (or `grep -F -v`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it's traditional to use `/` as the delimiter in a `sed` expression, you can actually use whatever you like.  So if you have `/` in the pattern you're matching, it's often easier to use something else, I typically go for `,` but it can be pretty much anything.  To use something other than `/` you may need to escape it though.  For example:

```
sed -e '\,^/var/run/saslauthd,d' /etc/fstab
```

You could probably do the same with the first one where you have a leading `:` if you use `\:` instead.

Comment: Also `grep -v '^/var/run/saslauthd'` would be enough, no need for sed here.

Comment: True, unless want to actually remove it from the file (as they mentioned in their question), in which case adapting a `sed` command is easier than `grep`.  I just adapated their `sed` though it does not modify the file in its current form